# Editar mysql ini em container

Tags: mysql, docker

Estou utilizando docker para gerar um LAMP.
Meu `yml` está assim:

```
    web:
     image: tutum/apache-php
     ports:
     - "80:80"
     links:
     - db
     volumes:
     - $PWD:/app

    db:
     image: mysql
     environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= my-secret-pw
     - MYSQL_DATABASE= lamp
     - MYSQL_USER= lamp_user
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD= lamp_pass
     ports:
     - "3306:3306"
```

Ao tentar acessar o mysql através de uma outra máquina, está dando o seguinte erro no workbench:

`Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded`

Vi uma galera dizendo que tenho que editar o `my.ini` e editar a seguinte linha com este valor :

`[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password`

Porém não estou sabendo como editar o `my.ini`.

Estou seguindo a solução correta?
Caso sim, como faço para editar o arquivo em questão?

Comment: Você pode passar como volume (`-v`) o arquivo de conf com o que precisa

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim Daí eu passo todo o conf, mesmo precisando alterar apenas uma linha ?

Comment: O correto seria você criar seu próprio `.ini` e passar ele no seu `yml`. Viu se esse problema acontece eu todas as versões da imagem do `mysql`? Pode ser que seja só na última, que é a que está usando.

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim na mosca. Defini a versão para 5.6 e funcionou perfeito. Vou postar uma resposta com o `yml` vai que ajuda alguém um dia. MUITO OBRIGADO

Comment: Boa, as vezes subir uma imagem `latest` pra produção pode dar problema mesmo ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente ao definir a versão a ser usada do mysql, e não deixando a `latest`, solucionou meu problema.

No `yml` abaixo note que defino a versão do mysql para a 5.6.
De quebra adicionei o `restart: always` para reiniciar automático os dois containers

```
        web:
         image: tutum/apache-php
         ports:
         - "80:80"
         links:
         - db
         volumes:
         - $PWD:/app
         restart: always

        db:
         image: mysql:5.6
         environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= my-secret-pw
         - MYSQL_DATABASE= lamp
         - MYSQL_USER= lamp_user
         - MYSQL_PASSWORD= lamp_pass
         ports:
         - "3306:3306"
         restart: always
```